# It sounds good to go to the club tonight. / The idea to go to the club tonight sounds good

Tags: sentence-choice

> **It sounds good** to go to the club tonight.
>
> **The idea** to go to the club tonight **sounds good**.

If I understand correctly, the meaning of those sentences is the same. Which version is more natural for native speakears? The first one sounds better to me. Is the second version more formal English?

Comment: How about "Going to the club tonight sounds good"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second sentence does not sound natural at all to me. At least in USEng I would not expect a fluent speaker to say:

> The idea to go to the club tonight sounds good.

This is certianly not formal. It might be rewritten as:

> The idea of going to the club tonight sounds good.

The first sentence:

> It sounds good to go to the club tonight.

is also rather unusual. User myacorn's suggestion of

> Going to the club tonight sounds good.

is much more plausible in my view. "It sounds good" followed by an infinitive and then an object seems awkward, although I can't specify any rule that it violates.